Do they even fit? Yes!

Right:

1: A direction. (4)
7: Beverages. (4)

Down:

3: Elder sisters. (4)
4: To satisfy. (4)

Up:

2: Greek letters. (4)
5: A stiff structure. (4)
6: For suppressing someone. (4)


Really clever puzzle!

The grid

 can be filled as follows:




 The answers are read in the given direction, switching to the other row/column when the end of the row/column has been reached.

 Right:
 1: A direction. (4) EAST
 7: Beverages. (4) TEAS

 Down:
 3: Elder sisters. (4) ATES ("ate" is a term used for an elder sister or elder female figure in Tagalog and therefore Philippine English)
 4: To satisfy. (4) SATE

 Up:
 2: Greek letters. (4) ETAS
 5: A stiff structure. (4) SETA (a bristle or hair-like structure on some organisms which may be stiff)
 6: For suppressing someone. (4) TASE (verb but can also be a noun: an electric shock produced when a taser is used to suppress someone)

